# Select * and sum in mysql in a same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to create one query that selects all table columns and new column "sum",
something like this:

```
SELECT *, 
       sum(amount) as `items_total` 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE ...
```

Any ideas??

Comment: You're going to want to `GROUP BY` something

Comment: item_total is sum of all rows in your table or else...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * , (SELECT sum(amount)  
            FROM mytable 
            WHERE ...) as `items_total`
FROM mytable 
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thanks its Just what I needed

Comment: @pey22 Could you mark the answer as correct? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try as per below-

```
  SELECT col1,
         sum(amount) as items_total 
    FROM mytable 
   WHERE mycol = <condition> 
GROUP BY col1;
```

Comment: Hello
what is col1? i need all my columns i have more then 30

Comment: This will not sum all rows, which at least I think is what is asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub-select to calculate the sum:

```
select t.*, (select sum(amount) FROM mytable) as `items_total`
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

consider a,b,c and d as column name in the table and colsum is the sum of that particular column.

I think this should work

```
select colname ,colsum from (select 'a' colname , sum(a) colsum from tablename union all select 'b' colname ,sum(b) colsum from tablename union all
select 'c' colname , sum(c) from tablename union all select 'd' colname , sum(d) colsum from tablename ) tablename where (condition) order by colsum asc;
```

If you just need the column name of all the columns in the table then use.

```
 SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='database_name' AND `TABLE_NAME`='table_name'
```